# Google APIs Library for PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

I am using the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) which I currently have working with the Codeigniter framework. I am able to display a book title and image when I manually enter an ISBN number in the API code.

Each result in the table should display the corresponding title and image from Google Books.

Any help would be appreciated with this. Also, if my code could be improved I'd love to hear, I'm still learning :)

My current working code is as follows;

**Controller**

```
class Items extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['items'] = $this->items_model->itemList(); 
// var_dump($data['items']) returns the following (http://pastebin.com/4XVS4Whb)

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
        $client->setDeveloperKey("MyKeyHere");
        $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
        $isbn = '0-7515-3831-0'; // <- I need to replace this with my DB array
        $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes($isbn);

        foreach ($results as $item) {
// var_dump($results) returns the following (http://pastebin.com/by50uLNq)
// var_dump($item) returns the following (http://pastebin.com/b4vdt38P)

            $bookTitle = $item['volumeInfo']['title'];
            $bookImage = $item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'];
            $data['bookTitle'] = $bookTitle;
            $data['bookImage'] = $bookImage;
        }
        $this->load->view('item_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Items_model extends CI_Model {
    public function itemList() {
        $query = $this->db->get('item', 10);
        return $query->result_array();
    }   
}
```

**View**

```
<table>
        <tr>
           <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
           <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $bookTitle ?></td>         
            <td><?php echo echo '<img src="'.$bookImage.'">';?></td>    
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output of this `var_dump($data['items']);` and this `var_dump($results);` from your controller. I will be able to provide and answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you already have Collections data, you can simply pass it to the view and iterate on view itself, as:

```
...
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$isbn = '0-7515-3831-0'; 
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes($isbn);
//pass in the $results to you view
$this->load->view('item_view', $results);
```

and on the view

```
foreach ($results as $item) : ?>
    <td><?php echo $item['volumeInfo']['title']; ?></td> 
    ....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```